# Probability that all the cards are spades?

Tags: probability

If you take 4 cards from a standard 52 card deck what is the probability that all the cards are all spades?

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to think of it in sequence, as in what is the probability that the 1st card is a spade, and then if the first is a spade, what is the probability that the second is also a spade, and so on. Since we need the first AND the second AND the third AND the fourth to all be spades we would need to take the product of these probabilities.

So,

$P(\text{1st is a spade}) = \frac{\# \:of \: spades}{52} = \frac{13}{52}$

Now there are obviously only 12 spades left and 51 cards to draw from. I'm hopeful you can take the reigns from there.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't require Mathematica. It's combinatorics, and answers are easy to find on Google such as [this solution](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091028163606AA0nVCr) on Yahoo answers.